# How do you graph the sum of 4 surge functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-modeling

I used the program R to calculate the values of the maximums and the points where the new function starts, however, I don't know how to use these points to graph the function I'm looking for. [Image of the results I got from R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sRKs.png)

Comment: This is a forum about mathematics, not a forum about R. You need to either translate your question to be about mathematics, or else ask your question in a forum where you can expect expertise in R.